# Есть ли способ использовать Redis в качестве хранилища для Http-кэша в Symfony 6.2

Tags: php, symfony, кэширование, redis

В общем-то, все уже описано в заголовке. Есть необходимость использовать **Redis** в качестве хранилища для `http_cache` в приложении под **Symfony 6.2**.

Сконфигурировать такое поведение в `framework.yaml` по дефолту не представляется возможным, т.к. доступны следующие опции для ключа `http_cache`:

> #0 5.631 !!    Unrecognized option "cache_provider" under "framework.http_cache". Availabl
> #0 5.631 !!    e options are "allow_reload", "allow_revalidate", "debug", "default_ttl", "
> #0 5.631 !!    enabled", "private_headers", "stale_if_error", "stale_while_revalidate", "t
> #0 5.631 !!    erminate_on_cache_hit", "trace_header", "trace_level".

Ранее, существовал **BazingaCacheExtraBundle**, который помогал решить данную проблему, однако, на данный момент дропнут правообладателем, либо же доступ закрыт.

Если углубиться более детально в проблему, то имеется **n**-ое кол-во подов в **k8s**, соответственно, каждый под генерирует свой `http_cache` в файловой системе.

Хотелось бы добиться такого поведения, чтобы при обращении к первому поду генерился кэш, а остальные уже могли его использовать.

**Какой профит:**

1. Используем меньше дискогого пространства.
2. Увеличиваем hit rate захвата кэша.

**P.S. Шарить дисковое пространство между подами не является возможным, имеется явное ограничинение на это.**

**UPD: Как вариант, видится написать свою имплементацию vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/StoreInterface-a.**

Comment: Буду благодарен за любую помощь в решении данной проблемы, всем причастным, заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/redis_adapter.html

Comment: @DaemonHK в приведенной вами статье ни слова не сказано о том, как сконфигурировать `symfony` под использование redis-a в качестве хранилища для `http кэша`. Просто заюзать redis и образаться к его инстансу проблем нет. Возможно вы не совсем поняли вопрос? `Symfony` имеет кофнигурацию `http_cache` в `framework.yaml`, эта настройка делает то, что берет объект `Request` как ключ и складывает для него объект `Response`, уже со всеми заголовками, т.е. минуя код приложения от слова совсем.

Comment: @DaemonHK в продолжение к предыдущему комментарию: все данные `cache[Request] => Response` хранятся в файлах, т.к. имеется единственная `Store` реализация `StoreInterface-a` из `vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache`.

Comment: Может это устроит https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/redis/ в качестве альтернативы? Нашел ещё [такое](https://github.com/Toflar/psr6-symfony-http-cache-store), но адаптер для Redis придется искать отдельно/реализовать самостоятельно

Comment: @lezhni ага, можно рассмотреть оба варианта, первый на nginx-e был понятен, но была идея шарить volume между подами, а вот вторая реализация очень интересная,благодарю. Если приведете в виде ответа, приму. Благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может это устроит https://nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/redis в качестве альтернативы? Нашел ещё [такое](https://github.com/Toflar/psr6-symfony-http-cache-store), но адаптер для Redis придется искать отдельно/реализовать самостоятельно